# web application design strategy on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to develop a gaming site. User can add other users as their friends. User will get points as he completes various game levels. Now I need to show the average points of all user's friends who had already played the game on its page(example: When a user plays a game A, average of points earned by his friends shall be displayed on the game A page. Similarly game B average points of his friend's shall be shown when he plays game B).

**My approach:**

- Store user's friend list(Max 1000) as multi-valued property in datastore and load it into
  GAE memcache when user log's into site.
- Use resident backend to cache all the user's game data(points earned for
  each specific game). A cron job updates the backend cache every hour.
  When user requests for a game page(eg: game A) for the first time, request handler contacts backend for computing average of friends points via URL-Fetch service.
- Now backend gets the friends-list(Max 1000) of user from memcache, fetches game A points of friends from in-memory cache(backend cache) and returns the computed average.
  Request handler after getting the average, persists it in datastore and also stores it in memcache so that subsequent requests to game A page fetches data from memcache/datastore without computation overhead on backend. This average is valid for 1 hour and re-computed again after that upon next request to game A page.

**My questions** :

- Is the above mentioned approach a right way to solve this problem ?
- How to implement an in-memory cache efficiently and reliably with backend instance (python-2.7) ?
- How to estimate memory and cpu required at backend for only this job ? (Assuming 0.1 million key-value pairs have to be stored with "userid/gamename" as key and user-points as value. User friend list max size is 1000.)
- If I have to use multiple backend instances as the load increases, how to load balance them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog post from Nick Johnson, about counters : http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/High-concurrency-counters-without-sharding

Use NDB datastore for :
- automatic caching, instead of your own memcache
- NDB has some new interesting properties like : json property with compression, repeated propeties, which act like Python lists

And have a look at mapreduce for efficient updating.

Comment: Firstly, I thought of own cache for storing all the user points instead of GAE memcache because the later is not reliable(most of user friends data may be evicted). For computation of average score, I need to fetch ~1000(max) friends game points for each user. This is not practical from datastore within time limit(1 min) and if I use GAE memcache,there is possibility that most of data will be evicted as it is not hit frequently. Once I compute avg  I shall persist it in NDB datastore. Subsequent requests fetch average from datastore/memcache without computing.